# Center the widgets lines of a QListWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

In a previous request from me (a few days ago), S. Nick and bfris have very effectively answered my questions and found a solution (the code just below) :

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QWidget,
    QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QListWidget, QTextEdit,
    QListWidgetItem, QLayout, QLineEdit)


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        addButton = QPushButton('+')
        addButton.clicked.connect(self.addrow)
        delButton = QPushButton('-')
        delButton.clicked.connect(self.delrow)
        upButton = QPushButton('▲', parent = self)
        upButton.clicked.connect(self.rowup)
        downButton = QPushButton('▼', parent = self)
        downButton.clicked.connect(self.rowdown)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(addButton)
        hbox.addWidget(delButton)
        hbox.addWidget(upButton)
        hbox.addWidget(downButton)

        self.listbox = QListWidget()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        vbox.addWidget(self.listbox)
        vbox.setStretch(0,1)
        vbox.setStretch(1,4)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')    
        self.show()

    def rowup(self):

        row_num = self.listbox.currentRow()

        if row_num > 0:            
            row = self.listbox.itemWidget(self.listbox.currentItem())
            itemN = self.listbox.currentItem().clone()

            self.listbox.insertItem(row_num -1, itemN)
            self.listbox.setItemWidget(itemN, row)

            self.listbox.takeItem(row_num+1)
            self.listbox.setCurrentRow(row_num-1)

    def rowdown(self):

        row_num = self.listbox.currentRow()

        if row_num == -1:
            # no selection. abort
            return
        elif row_num < self.listbox.count():
            row = self.listbox.itemWidget(self.listbox.currentItem())
            itemN = self.listbox.currentItem().clone()


            self.listbox.insertItem(row_num + 2, itemN)
            self.listbox.setItemWidget(itemN, row)

            self.listbox.takeItem(row_num)
            self.listbox.setCurrentRow(row_num+1)

    def addrow(self):
        row = self.makerow()
        itemN = QListWidgetItem()
        itemN.setSizeHint(row.sizeHint())

        self.listbox.addItem(itemN)  # add itemN to end of list. use insertItem
                                     # to insert in specific location
        self.listbox.setItemWidget(itemN, row)


    def delrow(self):
        if self.listbox.currentRow() == -1:
            # no selection. delete last row
            row_num = self.listbox.count() - 1
        else:
            row_num = self.listbox.currentRow()

        item = self.listbox.takeItem(row_num)

        del item

    def makerow(self):

        widget = QWidget()
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        r = random.random()
        r = '%f' % r
        print(r)
        label = QLabel(r)
        textedit = QLineEdit()
        button = QPushButton('Ouvrir reference art %s' % r)
        hbox.addWidget(label)
        hbox.addWidget(textedit)
        hbox.addWidget(button)
        hbox.addStretch()
        hbox.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetFixedSize)


        widget.setLayout(hbox)

        return widget


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the screenshot as it appears on the screen (everything is fine so far) :

[image]

If I extend the window to the right we see that the lines of widgets do not refocus :

[image]

That's what I would like to get :

[image]

It would be interesting if we could choose which widget whose dimensions will be changed for that it can adapt to the stretching of the window (in the image just above it is the QLineEdit of the Center).

I tried different things but for now nothing has worked in this direction.

Is it possible ?, and if so, can you help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try deleting the line `hbox.addStretch ()` and the line `hbox.setSizeConstraint (QLayout.SetFixedSize)`

Comment: @ S. Nick : Yes indeed that's right. Sorry for my ignorance.